# Moshi serialize generic classes "Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter constructor..."

Tags: android, json, serialization, moshi

I have following class hierarchy [Github Sample](https://github.com/abhishekBansal/MoshiListInheritance/blob/generics/app/src/test/java/dev/abhishekbansal/moshilistinheritance/MoshiTest.kt)

```kotlin
interface OptionV2 {
    val id: String
}

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class ImageSelectionOption(
    override val id: String,

    value: String,

    @Json(name = "active_image")
    val image: String?,
): OptionV2

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class QuestionResponse<T> (
    override val id: String,
    val answer: T?,
): OptionV2
```

And following test

```kotlin
        val childOptions = listOf(ImageSelectionOption(value = "dummy", id = "dummy", image = "dummy"))
        val childResponse = QuestionResponse<List<OptionV2>>(answer = childOptions, id = "child_qid")

        val parentOptions = listOf(childResponse)
        val parentResponse = QuestionResponse<Any>(answer = parentOptions, id = "parent_qid")

        val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(OptionV2MoshiAdapter.OptionAdapterFactory).build()

        val type = Types.newParameterizedType(QuestionResponse::class.java, Any::class.java)
        moshi.adapter<QuestionResponse<Any>>(type).toJson(parentResponse)
```

I am essentially attempting to deserialize `QuestionResponse<List<QuestionResponse<List<Option>>>>` type. This fails with following error

> Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter constructor for 'class dev.abhishekbansal.moshilistinheritance.QuestionResponse'. Suspiciously, the type was not parameterized but the target class 'dev.abhishekbansal.moshilistinheritance.QuestionResponseJsonAdapter' is generic. Consider using Types#newParameterizedType() to define these missing type variables.

I wish to be able to write a custom adapter for this if needed. As I need to be able to deserialize this in the Retrofit scenario.

Here is [more complete Github Sample](https://github.com/abhishekBansal/MoshiListInheritance/blob/generics/app/src/test/java/dev/abhishekbansal/moshilistinheritance/MoshiTest.kt)

**Update**

Finally got it working by using this

```kotlin
        // List<Option>
        val listType = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, OptionV2::class.java)
        // QuestionResponse<List<Option>>
        val qr1 = Types.newParameterizedType(QuestionResponse::class.java, listType)
        // List<QuestionResponse<List<Option>>>
        val listType2 = Types.newParameterizedType(List::class.java, qr1)
        // QuestionResponse<List<QuestionResponse<List<Option>>>>
        val finalType = Types.newParameterizedType(QuestionResponse::class.java, listType2)
        println(moshi.adapter<QuestionResponse<Any>>(finalType).toJson(parentResponse))
```

I am still confused about how can I write a custom adapter for this which can be supplied to `Moshi` instance which is supplied to `Retrofit`. So that it can be serialized on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Custom Adapter that worked for me. I have a couple of doubts in this but it works.

```kotlin
class QuestionResponseAdapter<T>(val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<T>) : JsonAdapter<T>() {

    override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): T? {
        return elementAdapter.fromJson(reader)
    }

    override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, value: T?) {
        elementAdapter.toJson(writer, value)
    }

    object QuestionResponseAdapterFactory : Factory {

        override fun create(type: Type, annotations: MutableSet<out Annotation>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
            if (!annotations.isEmpty()) {
                return null // Annotations? This factory doesn't apply.
            }

            if (type !== QuestionResponse::class.java) {
                return null // Not a QuestionResponse This factory doesn't apply.
            }

            // Handle Type erasure at runtime, this class does not need adapter with single level of generic though
            val parameterizedType = Types.newParameterizedType(type, Any::class.java)
            val elementAdapter: JsonAdapter<Any> = moshi.adapter(parameterizedType)

            return QuestionResponseAdapter(elementAdapter).nullSafe()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added a similar custom method.

```
protected inline fun <reified T> convert(value: SomeGenericClass<T>): String {
    val parameterizedType = Types.newParameterizedType(SomeGenericClass::class.java, T::class.java)
    val adapter = moshi.adapter<SomeGenericClass<T>>(parameterizedType)
    return adapter.toJson(value)
}
```

For instance you want to convert an object of `SomeGenericClass<*>` to JSON.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class SomeGenericClass<T>(
    @Json(name = "pages")
    val pages: Int = 0,
)

@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Book(
    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: String,
)

val book = SomeGenericClass<Book>(
    pages = 100,
    author = "Aaa",
    ...)
```

Then you should create a Moshi object and call `convert(book)`.

See also [1](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/591) and [2](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/support-json-and-polymorphic-classes-with-moshi-kotlin-made-easy-5853bdadc5b9).