# Moshi: Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter class for class

Tags: kotlin, moshi

I'm following the example in https://proandroiddev.com/getting-started-using-moshi-for-json-parsing-with-kotlin-5a460bf3935a as close as possible, but still fail to run.

In my Gradle, I have

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.8.0"
    kapt 'com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin-codegen:1.8.0'
}
```

I have a class

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Movie (
    @Json(name = "vote_count") val voteCount: Int = -1,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    @Json(name = "image_path") val imagePath: String,
    val overview: String
)
```

When I run my test as below

```
    @Test
    fun testMoshi() {
        val moviesJson: String = """
{
  "vote_count": 2026,
  "id": 19404,
  "title": "Example Movie",
  "image_path": "/example-movie-image.jpg",
  "overview": "Overview of example movie"
} 
        """.trimIndent()

        val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<Movie> = moshi.adapter(Movie::class.java)
        val movie = adapter.fromJson(moviesJson)
    }
```

It fails `Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter class for class...`

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, it's because I put the below in Test Folder instead of Main Folder.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Movie (
    @Json(name = "vote_count") val voteCount: Int = -1,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    @Json(name = "image_path") val imagePath: String,
    val overview: String
)
```

When I have move it to the main folder, it works (as the adaptor now can be generated)

Answer (score 0):

In another case you should read a whole stacktrace with exception, like this:

```
TestRunner: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter 
constructor for 'class SomeGenericClass'. Suspiciously, the type was not parameterized 
but the target class 'SomeGenericClassJsonAdapter' is generic. 
Consider using Types#newParameterizedType() to define these missing type variables.
... 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: SomeGenericClassJsonAdapter.<init> []
```

Then search for a solution. I found this one for my situation: [Moshi serialize generic classes "Failed to find the generated JsonAdapter constructor..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499216/moshi-serialize-generic-classes-failed-to-find-the-generated-jsonadapter-constr).